# adding a pattern to the end of each column

Tags: awk, sed

Say I have a file similar to this format :

```
"pop","hand stuff","test "
"non","no way","good "
```

except except of having only 3 columns it has hundreds. I want to add @ at the end of each column so the output is

```
"pop@","hand stuff@","test @"
"non@","no way@","good @"
```

If I only had a small number of columns then I could do

```
awk -F"," vOFS=, '{print $1"@",$2"@",$3"@"}'
```

But how would I do this if I have many many columns and I don't want to have to specify each column in the awk script?

Comment: That awk snippet would get you `"pop"@,"hand stuff"@,"test "@` not `"pop@","hand stuff@","test @"` just for the record.

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < NF; i++) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your columns don't contain crazy data (specifically, `\",` embedded within the string), sed is easier:

OSX/BSD:

```
sed -E 's/"(,|$)/@"\1/g'
```

GNU:

```
sed -r 's/"(,|$)/@"\1/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use awk's gsub function like below.

```
awk '{gsub(/",/, "@\",");sub(/"$/, "@\"")}1' file
```

Example:

```
$ echo '"pop","hand stuff","test "' | awk '{gsub(/",/, "@\",");sub(/"$/, "@\"")}1'
"pop@","hand stuff@","test @"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -r 's/("[^"]+)"/\1@"/g' file
"pop@","hand stuff@","test @"
"non@","no way@","good @"
```